# Mouseout triggers before expected in bootstrap accordion panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a menu with submenus, and I am having a problem regarding mouseout event on submenu.

The behaviour I look for is the following: When user clicks on the first level of menu items, the submenu items of this parent are shown in another div (this is important due to design requirements). If user clicks once again on this first level menu item, the submenu closes. If user clicks on any other first level menu items the corresponding submenus are opened.

So far this is working fine on my implementation.

The problem I am facing is in the second level of menu items. I want to achieve a solution in which when the user leaves the submenu without clicking any item, the submenu panel closes. I am trying to do that with a mouseout function, and nearly I achieve it, but the fact is that this function closes the panel before the user can click in any second level item.

I've been struggling with this for a long time and now I am completely messed and don't know where to look at. Any help would be appreciated. I apologize in advance, as I am mixing components that I don't know much, I am not savvy in bootstrap, JQuery, javascript, and I have a limited knowledge of CSS.

I have built up a demo in bootply: http://www.bootply.com/cq60yI6wZ4#

Thanks once more, sincerely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the element causing `mouseout` event to trigger is a child of the `.prova` element or not. This can be done using the following.

```
var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
if ($(e).parents('.prova').length) {
    return;
}
```

```js
$('.closeall').click(function () {
    $('.panel-collapse.in')
        .collapse('hide');
});
$('.prova').mouseout(function (event) {
    var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
    if ($(e).parents('.prova').length) {
        return;
    }
    $('.panel-collapse.in')
        .collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div>
        <!-- Inline script moved to the bottom of the page -->
        <div aria-multiselectable="true" class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">
            <div class="panel-heading" id="headingOne" role="tab">
                
<h4 class="panel-title"><a aria-controls="collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" class="closeall hoverExpand collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button">Moda Cosmética </a></h4>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-heading" id="headingTwo" role="tab">
                
<h4 class="panel-title"><a aria-controls="collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" class="closeall hoverExpand collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" role="button">Blog </a></h4>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-heading" id="headingThree" role="tab">
                
<h4 class="panel-title"><a aria-controls="collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" class="closeall hoverExpand collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" role="button">Tienda </a></h4>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="prova">
    <div aria-labelledby="headingOne" class="panel-collapse marc collapse" id="collapseOne" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li>Prendas Cosméticas</li>
                <li>Cómo Funciona</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div aria-labelledby="headingTwo" class="panel-collapse marc collapse" id="collapseTwo" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="panel-body">Blog</div>
    </div>
    <div aria-labelledby="headingThree" class="panel-collapse marc collapse" id="collapseThree" role="tabpanel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li>Moda</li>
                <li>Jeans</li>
                <li>Interior</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many many many many thanks, Rejith, your help solved my problem. I was unaware of the need of the check the trigger of the mouseout, thanks once more!